# Using API's in android studio

Tags: android, api, android-studio, tinder

I'm currently working on an app that requires match data from tinder but I have never worked with API's before and I'm not too sure how it works. I found some projects on github using the tinder api which I will link at the end there are just some parts that confuse me. Firstly all of the files are in python so is there a way I can implement that in a java file in android studio? Also it says that facebook authentication is required for the api to work so would having the user log into the app with facebook solve that issue?
https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder